# update redmine table via code

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am coding a plugin in redmine, I updated many times tables which I built, but when I tryed to update some atributes in redmine tables it did not wok.
 
In my case I want to update "identifier" attribute in the project table.

```
def update_project_field()
begin
  @projj=Project.find(params[:project_id]) #current projet
  begin

    if (params[:identifier_pr]) != "" || (params[:identifier_pr]) != nil
        @projj.update_attributes(:identifier => params[:pr_identifier])
        if @projj.save
          flash[:notice] ="ok"
        else
          flash[:error] ="error"
        end

    end
  rescue Exception => e
    puts e.message
    puts e.backtrace.inspect
  end
  redirect_to :action=>'reunion'
end
```

end

a success message is displayed but the update did not occur.
 what should I do ? 
thanks for help.

Comment: you can check sql query in rails server console, so you'll find whats wrong with your code if anything wrong

Comment: it works correctly (no errors found) but always I find the same problem(no update take place )

Comment: could you post stacktrace of your update action? Starting from params and finishing before redirect

Comment: irb(main):063:0* @proj=Project.find(:all, :conditions => {:id => 2})
  ←[1m←[36mProject Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `projects`.* FROM `projects` WHE
RE `projects`.`id` = 2←[0m
=> [#<Project id: 2, name: "name_projet_2", description: "DESc_projet_2", homepa
ge: "", is_public: true, parent_id: nil, created_on: "2013-03-12 13:46:48", upda
ted_on: "2013-03-12 13:46:48", identifier: "idetifier_projet_2", status: 1, lft:
 3, rgt: 4>]

Comment: irb(main):064:0> @proj.each do |a|
irb(main):065:1* a.update_attributes(:identifier => "new identifier")
irb(main):066:1> end
  ←[1m←[35m (1.0ms)←[0m  BEGIN
  ←[1m←[36mProject Exists (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT 1 AS one FROM `projects` WHERE
 (`projects`.`identifier` = BINARY 'idetifier_projet_2' AND `projects`.`id` != 2
) LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mRepository Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `repositories`.* FROM `repositori
es` WHERE `repositories`.`project_id` = 2 AND (is_default = 1) LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mWiki Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `wikis`.* FROM `wikis` WHERE `wikis
`.`project_id` = 2 LIMIT 1←[0m

Comment: ←[1m←[35mCustomField Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `custom_fields`.* FROM `custom_f
ields` WHERE (type = 'ProjectCustomField') ORDER BY position
  ←[1m←[36mSQL (4.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `custom_values`.`id` AS t0_r0, `custom_va
lues`.`customized_type` AS t0_r1, `custom_values`.`customized_id` AS t0_r2, `cus

Comment: tom_values`.`custom_field_id` AS t0_r3, `custom_values`.`value` AS t0_r4, `custo
m_fields`.`id` AS t1_r0, `custom_fields`.`type` AS t1_r1, `custom_fields`.`name`
 AS t1_r2, `custom_fields`.`field_format` AS t1_r3, `custom_fields`.`possible_va
lues` AS t1_r4, `custom_fields`.`regexp` AS t1_r5, `custom_fields`.`min_length`

Comment: AS t1_r6, `custom_fields`.`max_length` AS t1_r7, `custom_fields`.`is_required` A
S t1_r8, `custom_fields`.`is_for_all` AS t1_r9, `custom_fields`.`is_filter` AS t
1_r10, `custom_fields`.`position` AS t1_r11, `custom_fields`.`searchable` AS t1_

Comment: r12, `custom_fields`.`default_value` AS t1_r13, `custom_fields`.`editable` AS t1
_r14, `custom_fields`.`visible` AS t1_r15, `custom_fields`.`multiple` AS t1_r16
FROM `custom_values` LEFT OUTER JOIN `custom_fields` ON `custom_fields`.`id` = `
custom_values`.`custom_field_id` WHERE `custom_values`.`customized_id` = 2 AND `


custom_values`.`customized_type` = 'Project' ORDER BY custom_fields.position←[0m

Comment: ←[1m←[35m (1.0ms)←[0m  COMMIT
=> [#<Project id: 2, name: "name_projet_2", description: "DESc_projet_2", homepa
ge: "", is_public: true, parent_id: nil, created_on: "2013-03-12 13:46:48", upda
ted_on: "2013-03-12 13:46:48", identifier: "idetifier_projet_2", status: 1, lft:
 3, rgt: 4>]

Comment: As you can see, even after commit the value of the identifier is the same

Comment: are you sure that update is not being overwritten somewhere? ANd could you post this stack trace on some paste site, like pastebin or pastie. KInda hard to read it here

Comment: I trayed to put it in the same post but it is too long. and The web site do niot allow me to aswer my question unless after 8 hours. if you want I will send you this trace via e-mail. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful!

```
def update_project_field()
  begin
    @projj = Project.find(params[:project_id]) #current projet
    unless params[:identifier_pr].blank?
      @projj.identifier = params[:pr_identifier]
      if @projj.save!
        flash[:notice] = "ok"
      else
        flash[:error] = "error"
      end
    end
  rescue Exception => e
    flash[:error] = "Exception raised"
    puts e.message
    puts e.backtrace.inspect
  end
  redirect_to :action=>'reunion'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The identifier of a project couldn't be updated because , redmine use it in the url of the project. 
So before creating a new project, you have to be sure that the identifier is quite correct because once you had created it, you can't modify it.